# Algorithms used in ImageMagick

Tags: c, image-processing, imagemagick

I used Imagemagick in my project. I implemented a sub-image detection system using the compare command of ImageMagick. It is working well giving fine results. By reading articles i got to know that ImageMagick compares pixels of small image at every possible position within the pixels of larger image.And also i got to know ImageMagick detects rotated images and scaled images using Fuzzy factor.I was able to find the source code related to compare command.

```
const Image *reconstruct_image,double *distortion,ExceptionInfo *exception)
  585 {
  586   CacheView
  587     *image_view,
  588     *reconstruct_view;
  589
  590   double
  591     area;
  592
  593   MagickBooleanType
  594     status;
  595
  596   register ssize_t
  597     j;
  598
  599   size_t
  600     columns,
  601     rows;
  602
  603   ssize_t
  604     y;
  605
  606   status=MagickTrue;
  607   rows=MagickMax(image->rows,reconstruct_image->rows);
  608   columns=MagickMax(image->columns,reconstruct_image->columns);
  609   area=0.0;
  610   image_view=AcquireVirtualCacheView(image,exception);
  611   reconstruct_view=AcquireVirtualCacheView(reconstruct_image,exception);
  612 #if defined(MAGICKCORE_OPENMP_SUPPORT)
  613   #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,4) shared(status) \
  614     magick_threads(image,image,rows,1) reduction(+:area)
  615 #endif
  616   for (y=0; y < (ssize_t) rows; y++)
  617   {
  618     double
  619       channel_distortion[MaxPixelChannels+1];
  620
  621     register const Quantum
  622       *magick_restrict p,
  623       *magick_restrict q;
  624
  625     register ssize_t
  626       x;
  627
  628     if (status == MagickFalse)
  629       continue;
  630     p=GetCacheViewVirtualPixels(image_view,0,y,columns,1,exception);
  631     q=GetCacheViewVirtualPixels(reconstruct_view,0,y,columns,1,exception);
  632     if ((p == (const Quantum *) NULL) || (q == (const Quantum *) NULL))
  633       {
  634         status=MagickFalse;
  635         continue;
  636       }
  637     (void) ResetMagickMemory(channel_distortion,0,sizeof(channel_distortion));
  638     for (x=0; x < (ssize_t) columns; x++)
  639     {
  640       double
  641         Da,
  642         Sa;
  643
  644       register ssize_t
  645         i;
  646
  647       if ((GetPixelReadMask(image,p) == 0) ||
  648           (GetPixelReadMask(reconstruct_image,q) == 0))
  649         {
  650           p+=GetPixelChannels(image);
  651           q+=GetPixelChannels(reconstruct_image);
  652           continue;
  653         }
  654       Sa=QuantumScale*GetPixelAlpha(image,p);
  655       Da=QuantumScale*GetPixelAlpha(reconstruct_image,q);
  656       for (i=0; i < (ssize_t) GetPixelChannels(image); i++)
  657       {
  658         double
  659           distance;
  660
  661         PixelChannel channel=GetPixelChannelChannel(image,i);
  662         PixelTrait traits=GetPixelChannelTraits(image,channel);
  663         PixelTrait reconstruct_traits=GetPixelChannelTraits(reconstruct_image,
  664           channel);
  665         if ((traits == UndefinedPixelTrait) ||
  666             (reconstruct_traits == UndefinedPixelTrait) ||
  667             ((reconstruct_traits & UpdatePixelTrait) == 0))
  668           continue;
  669         distance=QuantumScale*fabs(Sa*p[i]-Da*GetPixelChannel(reconstruct_image,
  670           channel,q));
  671         channel_distortion[i]+=distance;
  672         channel_distortion[CompositePixelChannel]+=distance;
  673       }
  674       area++;
  675       p+=GetPixelChannels(image);
  676       q+=GetPixelChannels(reconstruct_image);
  677     }
  678 #if defined(MAGICKCORE_OPENMP_SUPPORT)
  679     #pragma omp critical (MagickCore_GetMeanAbsoluteError)
  680 #endif
  681     for (j=0; j <= MaxPixelChannels; j++)
  682       distortion[j]+=channel_distortion[j];
  683   }
  684   reconstruct_view=DestroyCacheView(reconstruct_view);




  685   image_view=DestroyCacheView(image_view);
  686   area=PerceptibleReciprocal(area);
  687   for (j=0; j <= MaxPixelChannels; j++)
  688     distortion[j]*=area;
  689   distortion[CompositePixelChannel]/=(double) GetImageChannels(image);
  690   return(status);
  691 }
```

Anyone have an idea about what are the conditions they are searching for in the following code snippet?

```
if ((traits == UndefinedPixelTrait) ||
  666             (reconstruct_traits == UndefinedPixelTrait) ||
  667             ((reconstruct_traits & UpdatePixelTrait) == 0))
```

Comment: you found the compare function, what stops you from finding the rest you want to know?

Comment: IM 7 introduces color traits for managing channels. The snippet in question is skipping data-stream/packets if the trait is not defined, or no data to compare.

Comment: @Piglet I was able to understand the behavior of the algorithm roughly. but when i searched for the conditions they are checking for, i just found following values.
  
  134   UndefinedPixelTrait = 0x000000,
  135   CopyPixelTrait = 0x000001,
  136   UpdatePixelTrait = 0x000002,
  137   BlendPixelTrait = 0x000004 in the imageMagick documentation and its not clear for me for what these values are for.

Comment: The purpose of `fuzz` is to allow pixels to have a slightly **different colour** yet still compare as matching. It is **NOT** for allowing shifted, scaled or rotated elements to match.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're wondering how these values are used:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/3-8a-bit-flags-and-bit-masks/

Those values are nothing but different bits. They are different so you can combine them and check them in a disambiguous way.

In case you don't know the meaning of UndefinedPixelTraits and so on, just google the word and you'll end up in the ImageMagick documentation:

https://www.imagemagick.org/include/porting.php

> Pixel Traits
>
> Each pixel channel includes one or more of these traits:
>
> Undefined no traits associated with this pixel channel Copy do not
>   update this pixel channel, just copy it Update update this pixel
>   channel Blend blend this pixel channel with the alpha mask if it's
>   enabled We provide these methods to set and get pixel traits:
>
> GetPixelAlphaTraits()    SetPixelAlphaTraits() GetPixelBlackTraits()
>   SetPixelBlackTraits() GetPixelBlueTraits()     SetPixelBlueTraits()
>   GetPixelCbTraits()       SetPixelCbTraits() GetPixelChannelTraits() 
>   SetPixelChannelTraits() GetPixelCrTraits()       SetPixelCrTraits()
>   GetPixelGrayTraits()     SetPixelGrayTraits() GetPixelGreenTraits()
>   SetPixelGreenTraits() GetPixelIndexTraits()    SetPixelIndexTraits()
>   GetPixelMagentaTraits()  SetPixelMagentaTraits() GetPixelRedTraits()
>   SetPixelRedTraits() GetPixelYellowTraits()   SetPixelYellowTraits()
>   GetPixelYTraits()        SetPixelYTraits() For convenience you can set
>   the active trait for a set of pixel channels with a channel mask and
>   this method:
>
> SetImageChannelMask() Previously MagickCore methods had channel
>   analogs, for example, NegateImage() and NegateImageChannels(). The
>   channel analog methods are no longer necessary because the pixel
>   channel traits specify whether to act on a particular pixel channel or
>   whether to blend with the alpha mask. For example, instead of
>
> NegateImageChannel(image,channel); we use:
>
> channel_mask=SetImageChannelMask(image,channel);
>   NegateImage(image,exception); (void)
>   SetImageChannelMask(image,channel_mask);

If you want to know how and why each method is handling those flags read the respective documentation or the code itself.